# Add a div arround a while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have this script.

```
var $bigList = $('.list-products'), group;
while((group = $bigList.find('li:gt(3):lt(4)').remove()).length) {
    $('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).appendTo('.box-products');
}
```

But i want a div around every .

```
$('<div class="container"><ul class="list-products"/>').append(group).appendTo('.box-products');
```

But that is not working. What do i wrong?

Comment: How come so few seem to think describing how *that is not working* is a useful thing to add to a question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a div, but not actually adding the `<ul>` tag as a child, try something like:

```
 $('<div class="container"></div>').append($('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group)).appendTo('.box-products');
```

or if that still doesn't solve your problem, you may want to split the statement.

```
 var $div = $("<div></div>");
 $div.append($('<ul class="list-products"/>').append(group)).appendTo('.box-products');
```

I don't have time to make a fiddle, but I can if neither of these solutions work.